# Old problem with text with question marks

Tags: php, html, mysql, encoding

I am new here, but my problem is old like world.
I am starting developer, start to develop simple website on php with mysql and some packages (with composer).
Problem is with latvian language, all simple letters what is same with english, is ok, but our "Ā, Č, Ē..." all shown like question marks.
Page what need to display is encoded with:
`<meta charset="ISO-8859-1" />`
I try many different ways with different charsets, nothing work.
MySQL database collation is "utf8mb4_general_ci, text in database is "nepieciešamās zināšanas un ierīces" but in website is "nepiecie?am?s zin??anas un ier?ces".
I cant find any sollution, in this project is another place to add articles and there all is ok, no problem with text, but those pages encodings and database collation is same, can someone help me?

Comment: declare the html page to be `UTF-8`. If that doesn't work run `SET NAMES 'UTF8'` before any other sql query in your connection to it

Comment: See "question marks" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: I tryed to declare in "<html lang="utf-8">"
and also in meta "<meta charset="UTF-8">" in meta i tryed many different types what i find in the depths of the internet

Its didnt work, i tryed some solution, but it wont work too, maybe will help if i tell what i use:
"PHP": "8.0",
"MySQL": "5.2",

And some packages from packagist:
"nikic/fast-route": "^1.3",
"twig/twig": "^2.0",
"doctrine/orm": "^2.11",
"tinymce/tinymce": "^6.0"

But in this project are older pages where can add new articles and there all it ok, but in new section no